# run windows application on startup from registry with parameters

Tags: windows, registry, startup

I've added the following to the `run` section `string value` in registry:

```
Value name
Nginx
Value data
nginx -c D:/Webservers/Nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

However, nginx doesn't start with these params, what's missing?

Comment: Provide the full path to nginx.exe to ensure that Windows can find the file.  So not just nginx but c:\foo\bar\baz\nginx.exe, where-ever it is installed.

Comment: It can, the path to nginx is in the `PATH` and I can resolve it inside `cmd`. But I will add anyway